# Network manager is adding unwanted rules to iptables

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, iptables

I am trying to create a wifi router using ubuntu 16 and network manager. I can create the wifi hotspot and an ethernet connection but no device that sits downstream over ethernet can ping a device connected via the wifi hotspot.

I have found the problem. Which is when network manager creates the wifi hotspot the ip tables rules get changed to

```
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  wlp3s0 *       10.42.0.0/24         0.0.0.0/0
2        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  wlp3s0 wlp3s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      wlp3s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
4        0     0 REJECT     all  --  wlp3s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Rule on line 3 prevents any other connection from reaching devices that are connected via wifi. How can I set up my wifi hotspot using nmcli to leave out this rule?

Comment: Line 2 accepts all traffic so what makes you think line 3 is a problem ?

Comment: Firewall rules run from the top down. Rule 2 accepts any traffic originating from and going to your `wlp3s0` interface. This rule takes priority over rejecting any traffic to that same interface. Best practice is implicit deny and then open specific ports/services that you need.

Comment: @hamiheim no that is not best practice. First best practice is REJECT not DROP for reasons outlined here - http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject . Also if you make DROP the default policy you will lock yourself out if you flush IPTABLES. Best make REJECT the last rule in your table after your ACCEPT rules.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen My bad, I didn't articulate the distinction between deny and reject. My thinking was inline with reject not drop, I've never properly been corrected on the definition of DENY versus REJECT. DOH! Won't make that mistake again.

Comment: It is a common mistake which is why I pointed it out. Yea, cracker tools do not play nice and do not time out.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen line 2 accepts all traffic from wlp3s0 to wlp3s0. I need all traffic from all interfaces to be allowed to go out wlp3s0

Comment: What are you trying to do ? what is the point of using iptables if you are allowing all traffic? Are you trying to redirect traffic? run a router ? What interfaces do you have ? As you know how to allow wlp3s0, allow your other interfaces or simply leave the interface blank as you are accepting all traffic anyways. Why write rules to allow all traffic on all interfaces ?